# how to filter display based on date in Rails (easy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

```
def home
    @guide = Guide.all
    @finished = Guide.where(:date_starting <= Time.now)
end
```

Why doesn't this work? In my controller I want to compare the the start date of the objects in my database with the Time now, so that Exhibitions that are no longer on display are in the '@finished' variable. I get the error 'comparison of Symbol with Time failed'.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `where()` method does not do comparisons like you show here.

Your query could be written like so:

```
Guide.where('date_starting <= ?', Time.now)
```

or

```
Guide.where('date_starting <= :now', {now: Time.now})
```

Comment: Thanks man, so is there a more 'clean' way to write this then? using something like a '<=>'
  guide = Guide.where('date_starting >= ?', Time.now)
  finished = Guide.where('date_starting <= ?', Time.now)

Comment: @rico_mac Do you mean like `Guide.where('date_starting BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day)` or `Guide.where('date_starting >= ? AND date_starting <= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day)` ?

Comment: You know what @unixmonkey, I am not all together sure. I am pretty new to all this. This is the code as is at the minute, don't know if its any good but I think it does the job, right? 

  guide = Guide.where('date_ending > ?', Time.now)
  guide = guide.order(:date_starting)
  finished = Guide.where('date_ending < ?', Time.now)
  finished = finished.order(:date_starting)